# Infinite Recursive Loop In Java

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I'm a new programmer, in my sophomore year of college to be exact. I completed a programming assignment about recursion and received my feedback yesterday. There were two bugs in my program and I'm not sure how to resolve them. The goal of the assignment was to use recursion to display the path and number of connections between the logged in user and the entered user.

Example: Assume the logged in user is Joseph and this is the hierarchy:

Joseph is connected with Zane, Zane is connected with Mike, Mike is connected with Ricky, and Ricky is connected with Tom.

If the entered user was Tom, the output should look like this:

Joseph -> Zane -> Mike -> Ricky -> Tom

There would be 3 degrees of separation between you and Tom

(The degree of separation does not count the initial user and target user)

First bug: My professor mentioned in my feedback that he created this hierarchy;

han -> chewy

He logged in as han and entered chewy as the target user. My program should have shown a message that the number of degrees is 0, but it did not.

Second bug: My professor also mentioned that my program resulted in an infinite recursive loop. He set up this hierarchy;

Anakin -> Padme

Padme -> Palpatine

Palpatine -> Padme

Palpatine - Chewy

Anakin gets his connections, which is padme. Recursive call again for padme. Padme gets her connections, which is palpatine. Recursive call again for palpatine. Palpatine gets his connections, which is padme. Recursive call again for padme which starts the padme > palpatine track over again. He said to fix this, I need to keep track of the users that were already checked and not recursively call the method again if I've already checked the user. The extra check is another base case that will stop the recursion. However, I'm not sure where to start to fix this in my program. This is my source code:

```
public class DegreeOfSeparationAction implements MenuAction {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Scanner scanner, UserRepository userRepository, LinkedInUser loggedInUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Enter the username of the user you want to find the degree of separation with:");
                String enteredUsername = scanner.nextLine();
                List<LinkedInUser> users = userRepository.retrieveAll();
                LinkedInUser enterUser = userRepository.retrieve(enteredUsername);
                
                List<LinkedInUser> path = new ArrayList<>();
                long degrees = getDegreeSeparation(loggedInUser, enterUser, path);
                if (loggedInUser.equals(enterUser)) {
                    System.out.println("The target user cannot be the logged in user.");
                }
                if(degrees == 0) {
                    System.out.println("There are " + degrees + " degrees of separation between you and " + enteredUsername);
                }
                    System.out.println("There are " + degrees + " degrees of separation between you and " + enteredUsername);
                    showPath(loggedInUser, enterUser, path);
              
                return true;
    }

    private long getDegreeSeparation(LinkedInUser loggedInUser, LinkedInUser enterUser, List<LinkedInUser> path) {
        for (LinkedInUser user : loggedInUser.getConnections()) {
                path.add(user); 
                long degrees = getDegreeSeparation(user, enterUser, path);
                if (degrees != -1) {
                    return degrees + 1;
                }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void showPath(LinkedInUser loggedInUser, LinkedInUser enterUser, List<LinkedInUser> path) {
        System.out.print(loggedInUser.getUsername());
        for (LinkedInUser user : path) {
            System.out.print(" -> " + user.getUsername());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where to start. I tried plenty of different things after looking through my notes again.. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: *"My program should have shown a message that the number of degrees is 0, but it did not."* -- In general questions about bugs should show example input ( ✔️ ), expected output ( ✔️ ), and actual output (❌), not just "it didn't work".

Comment: Have you tried following the program in a debugger? A debugger should be included with an IDE. It allows you to follow program execution, step-by-step, while monitoring the values of variables.

Answer (score 2):

For the second issue: Keep track of who you have visited!

Before you recur on separation, check if you have already visited them. If you have visited this person, then you will already check their tree!

But there might be a 'shorter' path to a given person. You are doing a Depth First Search, but doing a Breadth First Search would guarantee the shortest path (see Dijkstra's Algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

I've written a pseudo fix
(forgive my syntax, just try to follow the logic)

```
private long getDegreeSeparation(LinkedInUser loggedInUser, LinkedInUser enterUser, List<LinkedInUser> path, Set<LinkedInUser> visited) { // EDITS
    for (LinkedInUser user : loggedInUser.getConnections()) {
        if (visited.contains(user)) { // NEW
            // BREAK / SKIP / NEXT USER
        }
        path.add(user); 
        visited.add(user); // NEW
        long degrees = getDegreeSeparation(user, enterUser, path, visited);
        if (degrees != -1) {
            return degrees + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Not sure about the first issue though, good luck!

Edit: It is likely easier to keep a 'static' set of visited which exists outside of the recursive loop.

Comment: This answer is nice, but for the OP, you should be able to ask a lab teaching assistant or your instructor these questions.  Have you tried that?  It's a good habit to be in.